# How to disable interface just for NetworkManager in Kali Linux?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, networkmanager, network-interface

I have two WLAN interfaces, and I want to disable one of them for NetworkManager, so that if I run something like `service network-manager stop`, all the interfaces should stop except on of the WLAN interfaces.

I checked only certain things, and I found that I need to specify something like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:MAC_OF_MY_WLAN_INTERFACE_I
```

The point is that, I have specified the MAC of the interface that I want not to be touched, but then again, when I run `service network-manager stop`, they are both disabled. Please note that the interface that I want to keep active is `wlan1`. Any ideas, how can I disable an interface for NetworkManager, so it cannot manipulate the interface?

Answer (score 2):

To disable your interface run the following command:

```
ip link set wlan0 down
```

To disable it at boot edit `/etc/rc.local` add the following line :

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

before the `"exit 0"` line .

Comment: I just want to disable the interface for NetworkManager, so that, if I have an interface that is connected to the Internet, after running `service network-manager stop`, I want that interface still to be up and have Internet connection.

Comment: init is already root when it executes `rc.local`. Don't use `sudo` where it's not needed.